# Receive SMS from numbers stored in a database

Tags: java, android, database, sms

I have a database of numbers that its users on the app store.
I want to get a SMS that comes only from these numbers.
Basically what I should do?

Please help me.Thank you.

DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PhoneNumber.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "number_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NUMBER";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("Create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NUMBER INTEGER)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String number){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,number);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public ArrayList getAllrecord(){

    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from admin", null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast()== false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("number")));

        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

ReceiveMessage:

```
public class ReceiveMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

final SmsManager mysms = SmsManager.getDefault();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle mybundel = intent.getExtras();
    try {

        if(mybundel !=null){
            final Object[] messageContent=(Object[])mybundel.get("pdus");
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i=0;i<messageContent.length;i++){

                SmsMessage mynewsms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messageContent[i]);
                NewMessageNotification nome = new NewMessageNotification();
                nome.notify(context,mynewsms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress(),mynewsms.getDisplayMessageBody(),i);
                i++;

                String smsBody = mynewsms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = mynewsms.getOriginatingAddress();

                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";



            }
            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //this will update the UI with message
            SmsInbox inst = SmsInbox.instance();
            inst.updateList(smsMessageStr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

    }
}
```

smsInbox:

```
public class SmsInbox extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private static SmsInbox inst;
ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView smsListView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public static SmsInbox instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_inbox);
    smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SmsList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null,
                null, null);

        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");

        if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "SMS From: " + cursor.getString(indexAddr) +
                    "\n" + cursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try {
        String[] smsMessages = smsMessagesList.get(pos).split("\n");
        String address = smsMessages[0];
        String smsMessage = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; ++i) {
            smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
        }

        String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
        smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
        Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menuRight) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.Home_page) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.not_pay) {

        if (SmsInbox.this.drawer != null && SmsInbox.this.drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            SmsInbox.this.drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            SmsInbox.this.startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

        }

    } else if (id == R.id.date_pay) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.bill_sms) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.help_menu) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.for_us) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.exit_app) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Database table :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must declare a function in your DatabaseHelper.java to check number existence.

```
public bool isExists(String Number)
```

which has a query like this :

```
Select count(*) from number_table where number = 'Number'
```

then in add these codes in your Receiver

```
String smsBody = mynewsms.getMessageBody().toString();
String address = mynewsms.getOriginatingAddress();
if(dbHelper.isExists(address)){
      smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
      smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
}
```

Comment: PS: Don't forget to add required Permissions ;)

Comment: Koorosh Ghorbani Thanks for your reply.